# Defining Image location in settings file django

Tags: python, django

So I started working on this django project that I took over from someone else. There are several settings files that all inherit from a base.py settings file.

In this base.py settings file there are several static image files defined in there.

For Example:

```
LOGO_URL="/img/logo.png"
LOGO=STATIC_URL+LOGO_URL
```

This seems strange to define image locations in this way. Is this best practices? if not what is the best practice?

Thanks

Comment: Change LOGO to use os.path.join aside from that, it looks correct

Comment: This seems like an attempt to control common asset locations via configuration. Nothing particularly strange about it. One can place any desired configuration in `settings.py`. Having multiple settings.py files is also fairly standard practice (such as base, production, development, etc. each targeted by their environments).  Like Bob said, use os.path.join for max OS compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

More commonly you would see just the STATIC_URL defined in your settings, and then the logo would be accessed in a template with:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<img src="{% static 'img/logo.png' %}" />
```

[The docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files) give more detailed explanation.